# Sending HTTP Header Info with Qt QNetworkAccessManager

Tags: qt

I have the following code, and I would like to add some HTTP header info along with the call.  Anyway that I can do that?

```
void NeoAPI::call(QString apiCall) {
    if (this->ApiCall.contains(apiCall)) {
        QNetworkAccessManager* manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(0);
        connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(netReplyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
        QUrl url = this->ApiCall[apiCall];
        url.addQueryItem("memberid","76710"); // Set for backdoor debugging
        manager->get(QNetworkRequest(url));
    } else {
        this->requestResultText = QString("Call %1 doesn't exist").arg(apiCall);
    }
}

void NeoAPI::netReplyFinished(QNetworkReply *netReply) {
    if (netReply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) {
        this->requestResultText = netReply->readAll();
    } else {
        this->requestResultText = "API Call Failed";
    }
    QMessageBox messageBox;
    messageBox.setText(this->requestResultText);
    messageBox.exec();
    //delete netReply;
}
```

Also, if I wasn't using these inside a class, what would the `this` in the `connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(netReplyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));` be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, see the documentation of [QNetworkRequest](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkrequest.html).

You'll want to do something like:

```
QNetworkRequest request(url);
request.setHeader( QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "some/type" );
request.setRawHeader("Last-Modified", "Sun, 06 Nov 1994 08:49:37 GMT");
manager->get( header );
```

> Also, if I wasn't using these inside a
>   class, what would the this in the
>   connect(manager,
>   SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
>   this,
>   SLOT(netReplyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
>   be?

It wouldn't be anything. To connect a signal to a slot, that slot must be a member function of some object. The [Qt primer on signals and slots](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) explains this.