# ProtocolUnknownError upon sending SOAP request in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, soap

I am doing a simple example to send a SOAP request in Qt. The attempt is to use QNetwork resources and send a SOAP request to fetch cities in a country.

http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?op=GetCitiesByCountry  .

Please help; what is missing out. Thanks for any pointers/inputs.

Build machine - Linux Debian

Qt version - 5.7

SSL - 1.0.2 available.

```
qDebug() << "Support SSL:  " << QSslSocket::supportsSsl()
         << "\nLib Version Number: " << QSslSocket::sslLibraryVersionNumber()
         << "\nLib Version String: " << QSslSocket::sslLibraryVersionString()
         << "\nLib Build Version Number: " << QSslSocket::sslLibraryBuildVersionNumber()
         << "\nLib Build Version String: " << QSslSocket::sslLibraryBuildVersionString();
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Support SSL:   true 
Lib Version Number:  268443855 
Lib Version String:  "OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017" 
Lib Build Version Number:  268439647 
Lib Build Version String:  "OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013"
```

**Error upon running the code**

```
Network error:  QNetworkReply::NetworkError(ProtocolUnknownError)
```

**CODE**

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QtNetwork>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QNetworkReply>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    QNetworkAccessManager manager;

    QNetworkRequest request;

    //Set SOAP headers

    request.setRawHeader("POST", "/globalweather.asmx HTTP/1.1");
    request.setRawHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=UTF-8");
    request.setRawHeader("Content-Length", "1024");
    request.setRawHeader("SOAPAction", "http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetCitiesByCountry");
    //request.setRawHeader("Host", "www.webservicex.net");
    request.setUrl(QUrl("www.webservicex.net"));


    // Prepare SOAP request XML

    QString query =
    "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
    "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
    "<soap:Body>"
    "<GetCitiesByCountry xmlns=\"http://www.webserviceX.NET\">"
    "<CountryName>Australia</CountryName>"
    "</GetCitiesByCountry>"
    "</soap:Body>"
    "</soap:Envelope>";

    QNetworkReply* reply = manager.post(request, query.toUtf8());

    QEventLoop eventLoop;

    QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &eventLoop, SLOT(quit()));
    eventLoop.exec();

    if (reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError)    
        qDebug() << "Network error: " << reply->error();
    else    
        qDebug() << reply->readAll();    

    return app.exec();
 }
```

**Resources referred**

- http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/29856-sending-soap-request-using-QNetworkAccessManager-question
- https://evileg.com/en/post/233/
- [Qt Web Service post query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847433/qt-web-service-post-query)
- [Sending HTTP Header Info with Qt QNetworkAccessManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199039/sending-http-header-info-with-qt-qnetworkaccessmanager)
- [Sending an HTTP request using QNetworkAccessManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6204621/sending-an-http-request-using-qnetworkaccessmanager)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields

Comment: Couldn't hurt to use Wireshark here to find out exactly what Qt is sending to the server. That said, SOAP is nearly two decades old. Modern code should be using RESTful web APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `manager.post(request, query.toUtf8());` will overwrite your `request.setRawHeader("POST", "/globalweather.asmx HTTP/1.1");`

If you would like to use your custom headers and so on, use [sendCustomRequest](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#sendCustomRequest)

Or set the correct Uri in [QNetworkRequest](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkrequest.html)  and use this request in [QNetworkAccessManager::post](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#post) method.

```
    //request.setRawHeader("POST", "/globalweather.asmx HTTP/1.1");
    request.setRawHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=UTF-8");
    request.setRawHeader("Content-Length", "1024");
    request.setRawHeader("SOAPAction", "http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetCitiesByCountry");
    //request.setRawHeader("Host", "www.webservicex.net");
    request.setUrl(QUrl("http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx"));
```